# How to add a view to custom listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, view, addition

I have made custom listview in android activity which has progressbar. On top of that listview there is another progress bar which shows progress as day passes in the month. Now i want to set a bar according to the progress of the month progress bar in custom listview which has four progress bars. Please see the attached image.

[image: ProgressBarUpdate]

The progress of the month progress bar and the bar which we put in listview progress bar should be at same position means aligned and this bar which we put should move when the top progress increases as day passes.

In Layout file I have used LinearLayout where I want to put the bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dip">
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Top"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_width="250dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/LeftText" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextOne" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextTwo" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/outof"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextOne" android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/RightText" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="O"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextTwo" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Bottom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Top" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/CustomPro"
        android:layout_width="250dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progress="0" android:max="100" android:secondaryProgress="0"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/accountdataprogress"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/MiddleText" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="0%"
        android:textColor="#000000" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Middle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_width="250dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/Top">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/PuttingBar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dip"
    android:background="#00000000" android:layout_below="@+id/Bottom" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In Java I have done something like this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProgressListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ProgressList> mPList;
private TextView mLeft, mMiddle, mRight, mTextOne;
private ProgressBar mCustomProgressBar;
private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

public ProgressListAdapter(Context nContext, ArrayList<ProgressList> nPList) 
{
    this.mContext = nContext;
    this.mPList = nPList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return mPList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int nPosition) 
{
    return mPList.get(nPosition);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int nPosition) 
{
    return nPosition;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ProgressList mEntry = mPList.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) 
    {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customprogress, null);
    }

    mLeft = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.LeftText);
    mLeft.setText(mEntry.getValueText());

    mMiddle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MiddleText);
    mCustomProgressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CustomPro);
    int mBarPosition = Usage.mElapsed;

    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.PuttingBar);
    View mView = new View(mContext);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(2, 25);
    layoutParams.setMargins(mBarPosition, 0, 0, 0);
    mView.setMinimumHeight(25);
    mView.setMinimumWidth(2);
    mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(12, 56, 99));
    mLinearLayout.addView(mView, layoutParams);
    mView.invalidate();

    if(mEntry.getValueNumber() > mBarPosition)
    {
        mCustomProgressBar.setProgress(mBarPosition);
        mCustomProgressBar.setSecondaryProgress(mEntry.getValueNumber());
    }
    else if(mEntry.getValueNumber() <= mBarPosition)
    {
        mCustomProgressBar.setProgress((mEntry.getValueNumber()));
        mCustomProgressBar.setSecondaryProgress(0);
    }
    mMiddle.setText(Integer.toString(mEntry.getValueNumber()) + "%");

    mTextOne = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextOne);
    mTextOne.setText(mEntry.getValue());
    mRight = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RightText);
    mRight.setText(mEntry.getValueOne());

    return convertView;
}
}
```

But When I run It shows extra bar in progress bar like this

[image: ProgressBar]

Anybody has done kind of work please give me your hand. Waiting for fruitful reply.
Thanks.

Comment: can you show more code ?? because it seems that these is inside of a loop try to set the orientation of layout

Comment: In your code you show only one addition of `PuttingBar` but you obviously have a loop around or multiple calls to your `addPuttingBar` snippet. Also note that you have hardcoded your left margin to 30, not why you did this. Can you please add more code around `addPuttingBar` snippet?

Comment: Hi there, I added the full code. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @inazaruk Hi how can I give dynamic height of the bar as right now I am giving 25 but I want to give the height of the bar as the progress bar height. How can I give that? I have used LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT but it does not show the bar I mean the bar disappears. So How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add call to `removeAllViews` in your `getView` funcion:

```
mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.PuttingBar);
mLinearLayout.removeAllViews(); 
View mView = new View(mContext);
```

That's because `LinearLayout` accumulates views, and there might be multiple calls to your `addView` function. So you need to remove already added view before adding another `PuttingBar` with new margin.

Comment: Hi how can I give dynamic height of the bar as right now I am giving 25 but I want to give the height as the progress bar height. How can I give that? I have used LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT but it does not show the bar I mean the bar disappears.

Comment: Try `LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT`.

Comment: I got solution by putting the height of the view. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @inazaruk Hi would you please help me on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315486/android-custom-animation-like-airport-schedule-board