# Android custom animation like airport schedule board

Tags: android, animation, customization, uiviewanimation

I want to create an animation for the text like on Airport the flight schedule board does. Dropping from top and change the text on it. Here is the image. So When I click on button the text on the image should change with the said animation. Does it possible with android?

[image]

Please guide me how can I achieve this kind of animation in android?

**EDIT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/clockbg1" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/clockbg2" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/clockbg3" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/clockbg4" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/clockbg5" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/clockbg6" android:duration="150" />
</animation-list>
```

My Activity Class:

```
public class XMLAnimation extends Activity {
private static AnimationDrawable animation;
private ImageView refresh;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    refresh = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.simple_anim);
    refresh.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loader_animation);
    animation = (AnimationDrawable) refresh.getBackground();
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    animation.start();
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Now How to place vertically animated text on this images so it looks like the animation I wanted to create?

Thanks,
AndroidVogue

Comment: You gave me a nice work to do :)

Comment: @ingsaurabh, Yes it is. I want to implement it for my small project.

Comment: @AndroidVogue Do you mean Like HTC Mobile have Digital Clock have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got working library. Originally developed by someone else but I provided support for down version from `Froyo`. I hope this can help you out.

[AbhanFlipView](https://github.com/Abhan/AbhanFlipView)

Ref:

Library Developed By: [Emil Sjölander](https://github.com/emilsjolander/android-FlipView)
Animations Created By: [Jake Wharton](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids)

**UPDATE**

It has a document named `HowTo.txt` shows how to integrate.

Thanks.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks to @Abhan, @JakeWharton, @EmilSjolander. Finally I can integrate in project to replace the old idea using images with animation as `HTC` does. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @AmolGupta Yes unfortunately whole repository removed. Sorry for the inconvenience. I am sure you will get kind of open source project.

Comment: Looks like there is a copy of the repo at https://github.com/vincentChao/AbhanFlipView

Answer (score 1):

It isn't exactly the thing you want, but there's a nice 3-part tutorial by Kevin Dion that starts [here](http://kevindion.com/2010/12/android-odometer-ui-tutorial-part-1/) for creating a custom odometer widget that looks something like what you want. It should help get you started.

To get the effect of the top half of the letters falling down (if that's what you want), you can fake it by drawing the letter into a buffer image and then scaling the vertical extent of the letter to get a foreshortening effect.

Comment: Would you please let me know how to scale text in vertical position. I have used animation to flip page and the page flipping vertically as I want but not getting any idea about the text animation. I have updated my code. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Let's call each half of the display a "leaf". To draw a letter, I would proceed like this: create two Bitmaps the size of a leaf. Draw the letter in both bitmaps, scaled and positioning the text so that half of it covers one bitmap and half covers the other. Then draw each Bitmap into its corresponding leaf using the scaling/translating version of [Graphics.drawBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.Paint)) after computing the scaling needed for each half.

Comment: Here's a refinement of this approach: make a single Bitmap for the letter and then use drawBitmap to draw the top half of the letter into the upper leaf (which varies in height in your animation) and then draw the bottom half of the letter into the lower leaf (which does not vary in height). One complication is to that this will draw the lower letter into the upper leaf in the last three frames. To fix this, have the source rectangle select less than half the bottom of the letter.