# How to develop the animation like the Flight schedule board in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

[image]

I am developing an iPhone app in which I need to show countdown clock. I have to show it in a way they display the flight timings on the schedule board on airports. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315486/android-custom-animation-like-airport-schedule-board) but its in Android and I am almost illiterate in Java. Can someone help me how can I do this in iOS sdk?

Answer (score 1):

If question still actual: you can use [SBTickerView](https://github.com/blommegard/SBTickerView). Inside that project you can find good example which illustrate code. Required animation is built by [CATransform3D of Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

An animated 3D transform on the layer of your view will create the visual effect of flipping:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    view.layer.tranform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2, 1, 0, 0);
}];
```

An alternative ready-to-use solution to SBTickerView would be the [JDFlipNumberView](https://github.com/jaydee3/JDFlipNumberView).